# How to see the cause of an unhandled exception in a java REST service?

Tags: java, error-handling, jax-rs

When I get an exception in my REST Service the response looks like this:

```
Context Path:/test
Servlet Path:/resource
Path Info:/test/4325
Query String:fromDate=2014-03-06T11:00:48.785Z
Stack Trace
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.NullPointerException
org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:77)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:220)
....
```

I can find the cause by debugging the code but is there a way to include the cause of the exception? In this case the line where   the NullpointerException occurred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally your controller should handle all exceptions and return HTTP 500 for any server error like NullPointerException.
Either catch your Exception and return 500 in your controller or implement a custom handler that does that for all your rest methods.

Comment: The question was more about how to actually get a meaning full stack trace in the response. The response I get is HTTP 500 but with a useless stacktrace. But I did catch the exception and figured out how to return the stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by [Viorel Vesa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1881599/viorel-vesa) I caught the exception and added a custom response:

```
} catch(RuntimeException e) {
    StringWriter sw=new StringWriter();
    e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
    return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .entity(sw.toString()).build();
}
```